# Use M Value with POLYLINE.segmentAlongLine

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, linear-referencing, m-values

Currently I have a table with Begin and End M measurements.  I also have a route feature class.  I would like to be able to use the  POLYLINE.segmentAlongLine(start_measure, end_measure) method but since some of my M values are greater than the shape length of target route, it creates feature rows without geometries for features towards the end of the route.  I have also tried putting the M measures in the positionAlongLine() method but that is also creating the same output since it seems to function in the same manner.

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.9.

I know I can use the arcpy.MakeRouteEventLayer_lr with my data but was hoping to remove the step of creating a layer and then Creating a feature class from it.

```
sde_conn = arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute(working_sde)
temp_flds = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(p_fc) if f.name not in('Shape','OBJECTID', 'Shape_Length')]
temp_flds += ['SHAPE@']
print(temp_flds)
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(p_fc, temp_flds ) as i_cur:
    key_errors=set()
    for row in sde_conn.execute(p_t_query):
        route_id = int(row[0])
        event_id = str(int(row[1]))
        odd = round(row[2],2)
        ps_beg = round(row[3],2)
        ps_end = round(row[4],2)
        ps_len = round(row[5],2)
        trans = row[6]
        trans_id = row[7]
        trans_beg = round(row[8],2)
        trans_end = round(row[9],2)
        try:
            line=di_route_shape[route_id]
            begin = line.positionAlongLine(ps_beg)
            end = line.positionAlongLine(ps_end)
            b_m = line.measureOnLine (begin)
            e_m = line.measureOnLine (end)
            sub_line = line.segmentAlongLine (b_m, e_m)
            i_row = (route_id,event_id, odd, ps_beg, ps_end, ps_len, trans, trans_id, trans_beg, trans_end, sub_line)
            i_cur.insertRow(i_row)
        except Exception as E:
            key_errors.add(E)
```

Comment: See if end_measure is greater than shape length and skip some part of your code.

Comment: @FelixIP, as it says in the description, the M value is greater than the shape length.

Comment: Could you write an IF statement that checks if the M-value is greater than the length of the line. And if it is greater, then use the length of the line as the M-value instead?

Comment: @User1974, the M Value is correct and is used for linear-referencing.  The problem is I can’t find the method for getting the shape length measure using the M value on a linear-referenced shape object.

Comment: It's worth emphasizing that measure encoded into the line may not have anything to do with the length of the line. Measure could be a count on the number of jam doughnuts along the line. So using the encoded measure in the functions segment along line may not be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not a direct answer to your question as I don't think `Geometry.positionAlongLine()` or any `Geometry` methods directly utilize M-values, but here's a thought.  You're using `sde_conn.execute()` instead of `SearchCursor`, but hopefully the same logic applies.

You can expose the M values of the vertices:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('lines', 'SHAPE@') as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        polyline = row[0]
        points = polyline[0]
        for point in points:
            print(point.M)
```

So let's say your M-values go from 0 to 100', SHAPE_LENGTH is 82.68' or something, and you want to extract a segment going from 0' to 90' (according to the M-values).  In other words, we want to create a segment going from 0% to 90% of the original polyline feature.  So we can interpolate.

In this example our feature class has some fields (in feet), `begin_m` and `end_m` (which would be set to 0' and 90' for our hypothetical 100' feature).  Note that it would break if you had an `end_m` > largest M value.

```
def to_percent(val, lo, hi):
    percent = (val-lo)/(hi-lo)
    assert 0 <= percent <= 1
    return percent


segments = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('lines', ['SHAPE@', 'begin_m', 'end_m']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        polyline, begin_m, end_m = row
        
        # could also do polyline.firstPoint.M and polyline.lastPoint.M
        points = polyline[0]  # assume single-part features
        m_vals = [point.M for point in points]
        m_min = min(m_vals)
        m_max = max(m_vals)
        
        begin_percent = to_percent(begin_m, m_min, m_max)
        end_percent = to_percent(end_m, m_min, m_max)
        
        segment = polyline.segmentAlongLine(
            begin_percent, end_percent, use_percentage=True)
        segments.append(segment)


with arcpy.da.InsertCursor('segments', 'SHAPE@') as cursor:
    for polyline in segments:
        cursor.insertRow([polyline])
```

Now this might not give you a perfectly spatially accurate result since we're interpolating, but assuming your features are relatively small and/or you've chosen a reasonable coordinate system, that shouldn't be a problem.

EDIT: reading your comments, maybe you're just looking for the total length of the feature in terms of M values?  That would be easier:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('lines', 'SHAPE@') as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        polyline = row[0]   
        
        m_start = polyline.firstPoint.M
        m_end = polyline.lastPoint.M
        length = m_end - m_start
```

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth response.  I was thinking I may have to go down this route.  I just know the m-values will cross multiple points and didn't want to create function to get the correct percentages if there was something like a shape.m_method() that already existed.
Yes, the sde_conn() can be viewed the same as a s_cursor.
Don't know if you know this but I would suggest putting the s_cur within the i_cur.  This way you don't have to store the segments in a list() (takes up memory) and you can insert then directly (no memory). Also you would loop only "n" times instead of "2n"

Comment: Fair points on the nested cursors suggestion.  I tend to prefer this way for readability (one less indent) and memory is not often a consideration for me; if I wrapped the SC in a function that yields each row, we would preserve the readability and only one iteration.

That aside, my understanding is that M values are properties of points (the vertices of the polyline in this case) so finding a percentage may be the best/only way.  If I were king of ESRI I'd probably add an M value argument to positionAlongLine and segmentAlongLine methods, but use_percentage seems like a viable workaround.